# No module found in my python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I tried to read all the issues concerning the python's error
ImportError: No module named
I reinstalled all the modules I need using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

I also upgraded using pip

```
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

When runing `pip list` I get

matplotlib (1.3.1)

scipy (0.17.0)

numpy (1.11.0)

But here is the execution result :

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib

 >>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

I don't know what's happening! please help!!

OS ubuntu14.04

NEW EDIT
So some news: I checked out the install of python and I found different versions in different places. In the python2.7 case I have :

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/pyton2.7
```

While using `which` I get

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

But the `/usr/bin/python2.7` works really fine

```
cd /usr/bin
./python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> import numpy
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: Find where the modules have been installed (use `find(1)`) then make sure that the directory is in `sys.path`.  If necessary modify and `export` the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I added all the paths iin the sys.path but I still have `ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403273/possible-conflicting-python-installations

Comment: So after the edit, it seems you have multiple versions of python installed and everything works correctly if you use the right one. What is the question now?

Comment: Nothing just forget to tag it as solved

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the package has C extensions and they were compiled for an interpreter which does not fit the Python version you're trying to run it with.

(assuming you're running on Linux/OS X)
You can try using a virtualenv to install the package for the current Python version you're running:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Or you can directly provide the explicit path to the Python version with which you installed numpy.

Note that `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so` is the C extension which failed to load which indicates the problem.

Also see [Conflicting versions of python in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246000/conflicting-versions-of-python-in-ubuntu) for how to compile Python for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Install matplotlib like this if pip3 install didn't work for you

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Note - before doing check inside site-packages are present or not locate python using

```
which python
```