# python numpy ImportError: No module named core

Tags: python, numpy

Im unable to launch a python script using numpy - any idea what/where this core is?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/python/foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/packages/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    import ma
  File "/packages/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    import core
ImportError: No module named core
```

Comment: Could you explain how to install the numpy library?

Comment: only relevant code is "import numpy"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643549/no-module-found-in-my-python-solved

Comment: do you have pip tool installed??? If yes then simply do `pip install numpy`

Comment: bwt i do have a core inside numpy in the same location - no idea why its not finding it - packages/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages//numpy/core/__init__.py

Comment: from numpy import core   .... then do a dir(core) to see what you have

Comment: It's not trying to import ``numpy.core``, it's trying to import ``numpy.ma.core``.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python/pip installed? Check the directory of python and pip using `which pip` and `which python`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old numpy version (older than 1.7, which was released 4+ years ago) that still uses implicit relative imports within the package. The error you're seeing is a common issue with such imports, and has been addressed in more recent NumPy releases. Update NumPy, and this problem should go away.